# Can't seem to add JTextArea to JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I'm running in to a small snag here...I was trying to create a scrollable text area, and I've implemented it using the following code snippet, which I'm fairly sure is okay. I'd appreciate if you could tell me what's wrong with it?

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
textArea.setLineWrap(true);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
String s = "";

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    s += "asdflkjas;ldfkjas;lflsdkjfads;kfja;sdlfafsdf\n";
}

textArea.setText(s);

// method to add Component to a JPanel with GridBagLayout 
addComponent(scrollPane, 3, 0, 2, 2);
```

The problem is simple - everything works fine - the text appears normally, the scroll bars appear okay, the text is wrapped...but I couldn't scroll!

A few pointers, please?

Thanks!!
Baggio

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you are setting the preferred size of `textArea` to be a smaller size that the area needed to display the text so no scrollbars appear.

Better here *not* to set the preferred size and let the `JScrollPane` determine the size of the child component. Scrollbars will appear as expected.

You could use this constructor: [JTextArea(int rows, int columns)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea%28int,%20int%29)

---

Side note: Better to use `StringBuilder` when doing `String` concatenation for improved performance.